# How to get user input in do/while loop?

Tags: c++, user-input

I tried to use the do / while loop I asked about and fixed in my one function in `int main` to allow the entire program to be rerun if the user wants to, but it is rerunning the program without waiting for user input.

```
int main()
{
    int spoolnumber = 0;     // Number of spools to be ordered
    float subtotalspool = 0; // Spool sub total
    float shippingcost = 0;  // Shipping cost
    float totalcost = 0;     // Total cost
    char type = 'n';

    do {
        instruct();                     // Print instructions to user
        spoolnumber = spoolnum();       // calculate and store number of spools

        subtotalspool = stotalspool(spoolnumber);       // Calculate subtotal
        shippingcost = shipcost(subtotalspool);         // Calculate subtotal
        totalcost = tcost(subtotalspool, shippingcost); // Calculate final total

        // Print final output
        results(spoolnumber, subtotalspool, shippingcost, totalcost);     
        cout << "\n" << " Would you like to run the program again? [y/n]"; 
    }
    while (type != 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't added any code to accept user input. At the bottom of your loop, trying reading a character from `cin` into `type`.

Also, you may need to flush the output of `cout` first, before accepting the user input from `cin`.

Answer (score 8):

You haven't read any input from the user. You could simply do:

```
cin >> type;
```

But really you want to be checking that it is succeeding too, e.g. not eof or other errors otherwise it's still possible to loop forever if the user pressed <kbd>Crtl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> for example.

Checking if it succeeds:

```
if (!(cin >> type)) {
   // Reading failed
   cerr << "Failed to read input" << endl;
   return -1;
}
```

Which you could actually make part of the loop condition:

```
while (cin >> type && type != 'y');
```

The advice from Xeo about calling `cin.ignore()` is important to since you will almost certainly end up with more than just one `char` worth of input.

Comment: Duh thanks i missed that line. What do you mean checking that it is succeeding?

Comment: @awoodland: It's not so much about receiving more than one character of input, it's there to remove the trailing `\n` newline from pressing enter. Thinking again, yeah, that could count as an additional input character. :)

Comment: @Xeo - `\n` was the "almost certainly" extra input I had in mind. I'm not sure that every conforming implementation will give `\n` and only `\n` extra if no extra keys are pressed though so the weasel wording was intended as back covering :)

Answer (score 6):

Well, you never ask for input, do you? Add the following after the `cout` line:

```
cin >> type;
cin.ignore(); // remove trailing newline token from pressing [Enter]
```

Now, you'll still need the usual testing, if the input was valid at all etc, but this should get you going.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include a `cin` in order to retrieve user's decision:

For example:

```
cout << "\n" << " Would you like to run the program again? [y/n]"; 
cin >> someVariable;
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're not prompting the user for input.

You'll be more successful if you try something like:

```
cout << "\n" << " Would you like to run the program again? [y/n]"; 
cin >> type;
```